# nonlinearity after projection operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, projection

I have a question about the following result from a paper that I am currently reading.

---

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space with inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$, $C$ be a finite dimensional subspace of $X$, and $S$ be a bounded subset of $X$. Suppose a nonlinear mapping $F:X\to X^*$ satisfies:
$$\langle F(x)-F(y),z \rangle\le c|x-y||z|,\quad x,y,z\in S,$$
then the author claims that 
$$\langle PF(x)-PF(y),z \rangle\le c|x-y||z|\quad x,y,z\in S,$$
where $P:X\to C$ is the projection operator onto $C$.

---

I was wondering whether this is correct. I thought this follows from 
$$\langle Px,z \rangle \le \langle x,z \rangle ,x,z\in S$$
which is incorrect, since in that paper, there is no inclusion relation between $S$ and $C$.

Comment: How does $PF(x)$ make sense? If $F:X \to X^*$ and $P:X \to C$ then $F(x) \in X^*$, and so what does $P$ do to an element of $X^*$? (Assuming that $PF(x) = P(F(x))$)

Comment: I think that it is by identifying $X^*$ as $X$

Comment: @FlybyNight I think the author identified $X$ as $X^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the dual operator of P.

Comment: I see. And use the fact $\|P^*\|=\|P\|$.